# Does the document directory is removed automatically in iOS apps?

Tags: ios, swift

I've a simple question to the document directory. I build the folder by the following Swift statement:

```
open static let DOC_FOLDER : String = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).path
```

I store some files and create subfolders there.
And now I'm not sure whether the whole folder structure is deleted automatically if I uninstall the app or does the directory still exists and is only not accessible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the user uninstalls the app, the entire sandbox is wiped clean. If the user installs the app again, your app will need to recreate the folder structure again.

Comment: I have a strange issue that every time i build the app my downloaded files in document directory are deleted so i have to download them again. Is this natural? It happens only when i build the app. And im sure im not deleting the files everytime i kill the app and open it again. Because it only happens after building the app on the existing one i have.

Comment: @KeghamK. Are you building the app on simulator? or device?

Comment: on both. If i build the downloaded files are gone. But if i kill the app and start it again without building the files are there.

Answer (score 1):

Put user data in Documents/. User data generally includes any files you might want to expose to the user—anything you might want the user to create, import, delete or edit. For a drawing app, user data includes any graphic files the user might create. For a text editor, it includes the text files. Video and audio apps may even include files that the user has downloaded to watch or listen to later.

=> If you uninstall the app, the folder will be removed

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2406/_index.html